# App not running, shows NullPointerException

Tags: android, logcat

I am quite new in this. Now this simple app downloads image as a drawable from net, then converts it to bitmap (to store it in cache)and show it in the UI. 
When i run this, it gives **NullPointerException.**

**Code:-**

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mchache;
    ImageView imageview;
    Bitmap image;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


                imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        Log.i("shu","HERE @ calling loadimage");
       loadimage();

    }
    public void loadimage()

    {          Log.i("shu","HERE @ inside ");

        image = (Bitmap) mchache.get("img");
        Log.i("shu","HERE @line1passed");

        if (image==null)
        {        Log.i("shu","HERE @ imahe==null");

            downloadimage();
        }
        else if (image != null)
        {        Log.i("shu","HERE @ image!= null");

        imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
    }
    // converts drawable to bitmap
    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Log.i("shu","HERE @ drawable to bitmap");

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }
    public void downloadimage()
    {        Log.i("shu","HERE @ download image");

        String address="http://abd.com/absde.jpg";
        try{ 
           URL url = new URL(address);
         InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
         Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
         imageview.setImageDrawable(d);
         Bitmap bmap = drawableToBitmap(d);
         mchache.put("img",bmap);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {        Log.i("shu","HERE @ exception");
}
    }

}
```

Now according to logcat, the problem is here

```
            image = (Bitmap) mchache.get("img");
```

the code b/w two log info, so can anyone plz point out whats causing it. **And i am using LRUCache with the help of support library as its not present in api8.**

Comment: the `NullPointerException` is the easiest error, it can easy find the error from the logcat or check your code logic. so i suggestion before ask the question, need ask yourself: Do i really try to find the error? and Do i really can't find the error ?

Comment: will remember that.....next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not initialized the

```
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mchache;
```

do in **`onCreate()`**

```
mchache = LruCache<String, Bitmap>();
```

before

```
loadimage();
```

Comment: @PareshMayani What's in there? Edit Logs only.